# TYPO3: Class 'Tools_action_index_7c3e344226a5508b65ddf8993fcb960b3377b0d1' not found

Tags: typo3

I'm very new to the CMS TYPO3 and I ran into a problem after the successful installation. I cannot access the page, view and list in the navigation. My logs show the error:

```
Class 'Tools_action_index_7c3e344226a5508b65ddf8993fcb960b3377b0d1' 
not found
```

So I guess I am missing the action_index, but I don't know what I should create. A php file in the root of htdocs?

I guess it could be solved very quickly, but I'm still stuck and I can't find anything online.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this a fresh installation? Which version do you use? I suggest version 9.5 or 8.7

Comment: yes, fresh installation with version 8.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class name looks like a fluid template cache file which is not generated. Did you check the write permissions for your webserver? Depending on which Version of TYPO3 you have installed, the webserver need write permissions for `typo3temp` and `var` folder:

TYPO3 9.x composer install: `var/` and `public/typo3temp/`

TYPO3 9.x classic install: `typo3temp/`

TYPO3 8.x classic install: `typo3temp/`

[Directory structure](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/DirectoryStructure/Index.html)

[Security Guidlines: File/directory permissions](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/Security/GuidelinesAdministrators/Index.html#file-directory-permissions)

**You can also check the status and potential errors inside the install tool (Admin tools):**

TYPO3 9.x: http://your-domain/typo3/ -> Admin tools: Maintenance

TYPO3 8.x: http://your-domain/typo3/install -> Folder Structure

**Flush all caches in backend**

If write permissions dont help, click the red flush cache button inside TYPO3 backend ([right top corner -> flush all caches](https://kronova.net/tutorials/typo3/typoscript/typo3-flush-system-caches.html))

**Flush file cache on disk**

If this also not helps, delete all files/folders inside:

TYPO3 9.x composer install: `var/cache/`

TYPO3 9.x classic install: `typo3temp/var/cache/`

TYPO3 8.x classic install: `typo3temp/var/Cache/`

Comment: thank you for this great answer. Unfortunately I ran into more problems when I tried to reinstall again... I'll get back to here when I've managed to reinstall. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I finally managed to solve the problem. Thank you Steffen Mächtel for your hints with the write permissions. Thanks to that I realised that I couldn't change the write permissions of my folders (not even with chmod 777).

I am not sure, but I think the problem was that I had XAMPP as a virtual machine running so I couldn't change it. I didn't know there was a difference in XAMPP and XAMPP-VM. I solved my issue by removing XAMPP and do the whole install process using MAMP instead. Using MAMP everything works now. Thanks everyone again for the help.